# In macOS Photos, How can I sort images in "All Photos" album?

Tags: photos, macos

I had to recently completely wipe my computer and reinstall everything.  I just imported my photos from an external hard drive and that worked fine but the only issue is when i go into Photos, all of my pics are out of order.

Surprisingly can't find any way to sort by date of image (versus date imported which would be the same for all images). Am I missing something?

How can there not be a "sort by date" option for images in an album?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Photos Timeline view is sorted by the date embedded in the photo, not by date added. All other views are also sorted by the date of the photo except the All Photos album, which is date added. You can't change the sort view of any of the application created albums.

The last import view shows only the last import, and does not include photos from PhotoStream.

**Work around**: you can create a smart album and it gives a variety of ways to sort the photos in the new smart album (date range, title, keyword, etc)